# Is there call back function of JavaScript in Infinite Options by ShopPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am developing a product detail page with the plugin called Infinite Options by ShopPad.
I am trying to add HTML elements into the DOM generated by it, but it takes about 1 - 2 seconds after the page displays.

So I tried this way:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  function retry() {
    var $pluginHTML = $('.plugin ul');
    if (!$pluginHTML.length) return setTimeout(retry, 2000);
    $pluginHTML.css('fontColor','red');
  }
  retry();
});
```

It normally works well, but this is not the best solution.

Somebody knows if Infinite Options provides with callback function of JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that "Infinite Options by ShopPad" is Shopify's plugin.

Comment: If it does, then it would be in the documentation. Is it?

Comment: I had the exact same issue with their app. I delayed the load by 2 seconds.  `setTimeout(function(){ retry(); }, 2000);` Make sure you had added their script in your themes head. https://docs.theshoppad.com/article/109-decrease-infinite-options-load-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite Options contains a callback function you can tie into that is defined at `window.Shoppad.apps.infiniteoptions.ready`.

For example:

```
  <script>
  window.Shoppad = window.Shoppad || {},
  window.Shoppad.apps = window.Shoppad.apps || {},
  window.Shoppad.apps.infiniteoptions = window.Shoppad.apps.infiniteoptions || {},
  window.Shoppad.apps.infiniteoptions.ready = function() {
    console.log('app loaded');
  };
  </script>
```

Comment: yes, this is the correct code, i just got reply from shoppad support the same code.

Comment: Amazing answer. The issue has been solved. Thank you.

Comment: How to load infiniteoptions after ajax complete ?

Comment: Actually I want to infiniteoptions with quick view options.